# Flutter adding com.apple.security.network.client to *.entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

after moving current our project which that developed on `Linux` operating system to `MacOs`. i used `AudioPlayer` library and it works on android as well, now when i try to playing audio from network i must add `com.apple.security.network.client` to `.entitlements` such as `Debug` and `Release`

> By default, Flutter macOS apps don't allow outgoing connections, so
> playing audio files/streams from the internet won't work. To fix this,
> add the following to the .entitlements files for your app:
>
> com.apple.security.network.client

my issue is i can't find this files into `ios/Runner` and after reading some [document](https://flutter.dev/desktop#entitlements-and-the-app-sandbox) on `Flutter` website i don't get it how can i do that

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should open the `Runner.xcodeproj` file that can be found in the macOS file. The appropriate permissions you want to enable can be seen here:
[xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvwxf.png)